# How to create model objects of one model automatically when a model object of another has been added in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say for example I have a Model called Player. I want Model objects of Player created when new Users are added in django (from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`) such that each User object in User model has its own object in Player model. I know that I would technically have to use `models.ForeignKey()` to create a field in Player model and relate it to the User model and that I don't have to worry about deletion of users if I use the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` parameter in `models.ForeignKey()` but how do I automatically create these objects with like default values and such.
Initially this was my code to do so:

```
for name in User.objects.all().values_list('username', flat=True):
if name not in Player.objects.all().values_list('player_name', flat=True):
    new_player = Player(player_name=name, current_level_no=None, no_of_moves=None)
    new_player.save()
else:
    pass
```

But this would give me a DatabaseIntegrityError that "Models aren't loaded yet". So I am confused about what to do or how to go forward.

As always, I greatly appreciate all answers!

Comment: If you want to automatically create objects of `Player` when `User` object is created, you should use signals; But the error is complaining about something else entirely (you are probably running this code in a _standalone_ file and that's the cause).

Comment: @PedramParsian could you explain further why this error occured, so that I know what to do in the future?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

Comment: Ok I will, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals), specifically the [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save). Essentially, Django lets you define a function that will be run whenever your User model is saved. You'd use it something like this:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_player(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Player.objects.create(user=instance)  # instance is the User object

post_save.connect(create_player, sender=User)
```

Note that if you already have User objects in your database, this won't create Player objects for them; you'll want to do that by running a loop similar to the one you posted in the Django shell (using `python manage.py shell`). The signal will run on every subsequent save of a user model.

Comment: Ok, as I was digging on google for a solution I did come across signals but I wasn't really sure whether it was the right thing to use or how to use it in the first place, so thanks for that. But the second part of your answer puzzles me a bit, you say run a loop in python manage.py shell, but then every time I have a situation where users exist before the creation of Player model object, I would have to run such a loop. Just out of curiosity and for robustness, is there an intuitive way to automate this process as well?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. You only have to run this loop exactly once, to create the Player objects for any users that existed *before* you added the signal handler to the code (and if this is a new project and there are no previously existing users, you won’t have to do this at all). Once you add the signal handler, it will automatically create the Player object every time a user is added after that; that’s what the signal handler is for.

Comment: so the best thing to do is to add this signal handler even before I create superuser. Ok fine thanks for your help!